# Dreamweaver CS5 comment/uncomment

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, dreamweaver

How can I comment/uncomment the code with a shortcut in DW CS5? IS there ashortcut? If no how can I create for both of them? (It would be nice if both operations were done with the same key combination.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's been a while since I used Dreamweaver (defected to Expression Web) but from my understanding there is no pre-set shortcut(s) for commenting code.  You may be able to tie you're own to one via Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts > Snippets > Comments > (Comment Single Line or Comment Multi Line).  I'm not sure if there's a way to have it remove them.

Info found on help.adobe.com (for Dreamweaver CS5)...

[Generate a list of current shortcuts](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WS9C38B39D-A7F9-46e7-A689-A354790CA0C2a.html):

> A reference sheet is a record of the current shortcut set. The
>   information is stored in HTML table format. You can view the reference
>   sheet in a web browser or print it.
>
> 1. Select Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts (Windows) or Dreamweaver > Keyboard Shortcuts (Macintosh).
> 2. Click the Export Set As HTML button, which is the third button in the set of four at the top of the dialog box.
> 3. In the Save dialog box that appears, enter the name for the reference sheet, and select the appropriate location for saving the
>      file.

[Customize keyboard shortcuts](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WScbb6b82af5544594822510a94ae8d65-7763a.html):

> Create your own shortcut keys, edit existing shortcuts, or select a
>   predetermined set of shortcuts.
>
> 1. Select Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts (Windows) or Dreamweaver > Keyboard Shortcuts (Macintosh).
> 2. Set any of the following options and click OK:
>
>    - **Current Set** Allows you to choose a set of predetermined shortcuts included with Dreamweaver, or any custom set you’ve defined.
>        The predetermined sets are listed at the top of the menu. For example,
>        if you are familiar with the shortcuts found in HomeSite or BBEdit,
>        you can use those shortcuts by choosing the corresponding
>        predetermined set.
>    - **Commands** Allows you to select a category of commands to edit. For example, you can edit menu commands, such as the Open command, or
>        code editing commands, such as Balance Braces.
>    - **The command list** Displays the commands associated with the category you selected from the Commands pop‑up menu, along with the
>        assigned shortcuts. The Menu Commands category displays this list as a
>        tree view that replicates the structure of the menus. The other
>        categories list the commands by name (such as Quit Application), in a
>        flat list.
>    - **Shortcuts** Displays all shortcuts assigned to the selected command.
>    - **Add Item (+)** Adds a new shortcut to the current command. Click this button to add a new blank line to the Shortcuts. Enter a new key
>        combination and click Change to add a new keyboard shortcut for this
>        command. You can assign two different keyboard shortcuts for each
>        command; if there are already two shortcuts assigned to a command, the
>        Add Item button does nothing.
>    - **Remove Item (-)** Removes the selected shortcut from the list of shortcuts.
>    - **Press Key** Displays the key combination you enter when you’re adding or changing a shortcut.
>    - **Change** Adds the key combination shown in the Press Key to the list of shortcuts, or changes the selected shortcut to the specified
>        key combination.
>    - **Duplicate Set** Duplicates the current set. Give the new set a name; the default name is the current set’s name with the word copy
>        appended.
>    - **Rename Set** Renames the current set.
>    - Export as HTML File Saves the current set in an HTML table format for easy viewing and printing. You can open the HTML file in your
>        browser and print the shortcuts for easy reference.
>    - **Delete Set** Deletes a set. (You cannot delete the active set.)

Comment: +1: I have also defected to Expressions Web. It's come into its own in v4.

Answer (score 2):

HTML comment = <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-a</kbd>
CSS comment = <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-z</kbd>
Remove comment = <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-x</kbd>

For more visit

> Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts > Code Editing (Scroll all the way down)

Comment: I have tried, but this does not work.

Comment: Try again.  Works for me on CS6. Oh the joy.

Answer (score 1):

Under Edit --> KeyBoard ShortCuts  --> 
Current Set Drop Down : Dreamweaver Standard Copy
Commands Dropdown : Code Editing

Scrolldown till you see "Remove Comment" and select this.

Click on "Change" button and enter what keys you want to use and then press ok.

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.